# Change the camera that the Windows 10 camera app uses.

Tags: windows-10

I've plugged in a USB camera to computer and have opened the Camera app. How do we switch from the built-in webcam to the USB camera?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Unintuitively, the icon in the upper left that looks like it's meant to switch between your front and back camera will also cycle through your other attached cameras.  At least, this worked for me on a Surface Pro 4 (front and rear camera) with a USB Microsoft LifeCam attached.  The Camera application's version is listed as 2018.227.30.1000.

Comment: This worked for me on a Lenovo laptop with a built-in webcam and an add-on USB microscope.

Comment: In my WIN10 Camera app, the cycle camera icon is in the upper right. Upper left is a Settings icon

Comment: Worked for me. The icon was on the upper, right-hand corner. But worked as you described.

Comment: How did this icon get approved...

Comment: What a terrible design choice. I don't understand how Microsoft manages to consistently make design decisions this terrible.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the **Camera** app from the windows start menu
2. Select the [image: switch camera icon] icon in the top right corner of the screen to pick which camera to use.

[image: Select the icon in the top right corner of the screen to pick which camera to use]

Comment: This worked for me, not very intuitive if you are using a PC.

Answer (score 1):

From http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/camera-app-faq:

1. Open the Camera app.
2. Swipe in from the bottom edge to see the app commands.
   (If you're using a mouse, right-click within the app.)
3. Tap or click the Change camera button.

Comment: That works for Windows 8 but not for 10.

Comment: Actually, it works for me in Win10. But the camera you want to switch to has to be attached before the app will offer to change cameras. Otherwise, you will not even see the option.